# Random blank space in email content within words

Tags: php, email, email-client

There is a random issue I am facing with the PHP HTML email (using PHP mail function).

Sometimes, there is a blank space within words. For e.g. "Center Director" is appearing as following:

```
C enter Director
Center D irector
Cen ter Director, etc.
```

I have checked few forums, used trim(), etc. but it didn't work.
Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: *but it didn't work* -- what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you have your HTML all on one monstrously long line, try wrapping it on whitespace. SMTP requires lines to be shorter than approximately 1000 bytes. Excessively long lines will simply be wrapped by the MTA, typically with no regard to word boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding your email content using **base64**

```
$mail_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($mail_content));
```

Modify your existing headers this way.

```
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
```

Things to go through on PHP Manual : **[base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)** and **[chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)**